# Comparing accuracy of polling companies in multi-party system

Tags: categorical-data, polling

I'm trying to quanitfy how well (or poorly) different polling companies did in a recent election ina multi-party system (so, it's not as easy as saying how much they got the margin wrong in a two-horse race).

So, say the real election result was:

```
        Election CompanyA CompanyB
Party A   0.3      0.3      0.3
Party B   0.6      0.5      0.4
Party C   0.3      0.2      0.3
```

My initial thought it to do a Chi Squared using the sample size of each poll to  calculate the expected values (and the observed as counts rather than proportions). That way I'd have a measure of well each company's data fits with the external standard - but I'm not how can then ask whether CompanyA's estimate provided a significantly worse fit to the result than CompanyB's.

I'm sure there is some trivial thing I'm failing to understand, so happy to get an answer that sets me on another track.

***update** (thank to Peter Flom for helping get this straight in my head)*

Just to be clear. What I really want to know is who came the closest to matching their predictions to the final outcome across all the parties. So, I guess the best metric is the sum of the squared differences

Comment: This looks like a case where sum of squared differences might be awful, depending on the purpose of the polls.  If the purpose primarily is to call the winner, then you want to use an indicator loss: declare the difference to be small for a correct prediction and huge for an incorrect one.  On this basis company A clearly outperformed B when we assume "0.5" is slightly greater than 0.5 and otherwise the two companies had the same performance (neither predicted the majority winner).  When the purpose is to get close, use differences in the log odds, not raw differences, as a metric.

Comment: An interesting election result, of the kind that Russians protested about in December.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not a trivial thing that you are overlooking, but a big thing: What do you mean by "accuracy"? Is it sum of squared error? Sum of absolute value? Ability to pick the winner? Accuracy just of the winner's proportion? Something else?

Once you operationalize accuracy, then computing it should be straightforward, and then someone here can probably point you to a good test, if need be.

Comment: Cheers Peter, updated the question to make this clear. Thinking sum of squared differences is probably the best metric here

Answer (score 0):

I think you should force this into Pearson $\chi^2$ test, with the expected proportions given by the actual election results. The rest should fall in place in the standard manner, including the sample size. If the polling companies used a complex survey design to collect their data, you would need to correct for that and utilize an appropriate version of [Rao-Scott correction](http://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/proceedings/y2007/Files/JSM2007-000874.pdf). Alternatively, you could have a Wald test of the difference of their estimates from the election results, although doing this properly would require access to their sample designs. I am just thinking aloud here :).

Comment: Good ideas, as always.  I wonder, though: in many multi-party elections there is often a lunatic fringe element receiving a very small proportion of the votes.  A small--and inconsequential--error in the polling of one of those parties' returns could create a huge chi-squared value.  Do you really want to penalize the pollster so much for slightly erring on an inconsequential estimate?  (The same criticism would also apply to my earlier suggestion to use log odds for the metric.)

Comment: This is actually a question of empty cells and asymptotics, i.e., when is Pearson $\chi^2$ applicable. By that token, Wald test may work better in the sense of allowing a margin of error that does not involve dividing by a number near zero. Of course, @david-w can always omit these marginal parties and concentrate on the three-four-five largest ones, rescaling the resulting probabilities.

Comment: Actually I think it's a question of *purpose,* not of empty cells or asymptotics.  Even a lunatic can get a few percent of the vote.  In a sufficiently large poll (such as national exit polls) such proportions can still yield counts in the tens or hundreds: no problem with zeros or low counts there... .  The OP still has to decide exactly what he means for one poll result to be "better" than another and by how much.

Comment: Depending on the purpose, some trimming of the results might indeed make good sense.